# Why do some viruses have only one serotype, but others have many?

Tags: virology

Some viruses, like the virus that causes mumps, have only a single serotype, meaning that variants of the disease are immunologically identical. However, other viruses, like the influenza virus family, has many different serotypes. Why is this?